# Migrate python2 to 3 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So I try to migrate legacy python2 script to python3 but i got error on the some code

```
print ('resizing images')
for x in range(0, len(img)):
    imgResized.append(cv2.resize(img[x], (301 * len(img), 301)))

print ('resizing done')
source = interlace(imgResized, 301 * len(img), 301 * len(img))
cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

so i got error on `source = interlace(imgResized, 301 * len(img), 301 * len(img))`
that interlance its function for do

```
def interlace(img, h, w):
    inter = np.empty((h, w, 3), img[0].dtype)
    for i in range(h - 1):
        val = i % NUM_FRAMES
        print('index') 
        print(img[val])
        inter[i, :, :] = img[val][i / NUM_FRAMES, :, :]
    return inter
```

on the interlace function the error come from `inter[i, :, :] = img[val][i / NUM_FRAMES, :, :]`

this the complete stacktree

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sagara/Downloads/Printing Script/mnd_75 (latest).py", line 171, in <module>
    source = interlace(imgResized, 301 * len(img), 301 * len(img))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sagara/Downloads/Printing Script/mnd_75 (latest).py", line 126, in interlace
    inter[i, :, :] = img[val][i / NUM_FRAMES, :, :]
                     ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

and the print console from `print('index')`and `print(img[val])`i got this value

```
index
[[[239 236 238]
  [240 237 240]
  [247 245 246]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[211 208 210]
  [215 212 214]
  [233 230 232]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[229 227 228]
  [232 229 231]
  [242 240 242]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 ...

 [[149 151 152]
  [159 161 162]
  [200 202 203]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[156 158 159]
  [166 168 169]
  [204 206 207]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[128 129 131]
  [140 142 143]
  [190 192 192]
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]
```

its maybe because the img[val] its in not correct value?

Comment: What is `NUMFRAMES`? My guess is that `i / NUMFRAMES` is a float which is thus being rejected. You can try `i//NUMFRAMES`, `int(i/NUMFRAMES)` or some other rounding function like `ceil` and `floor` to ensure it is an int value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `i / NUM_FRAMES` is a `float`. You need to cast to an integer using the `int()` function or use the integer division operator, `//`

```py
i // NUM_FRAMES
```

Comment: And note that this is a change from Python 2 to Python 3.  In Python 2, int / int = int.  In Python 3, int / int = float.

Comment: NUM_FRAMES = 6 that static value but Yeah you right i just need use // and that works thanks